# Scalable workers in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, azureservicebus, service-fabric-actor, service-fabric-stateless

I am trying to migrate to service fabric existing solution. Part of it is the number of workers that listen queues. For example I have some queues:

```
Task1_Queue, Task2_Queue ... TaskN_Queue
```

For each queue there is some logic of processing messages of them, let's say workers. They do different tasks like generate huge report files and upload to `Azure Storage` or do small updates in database.

The question is how to design services in order to have good scalability of workers. My thoughts were:

Option 1 - Each queue will have separate stateless service. No easy way to autoscale single service.

Option 2 - Implement workers as separate actors, and have single stateless service to listen queues and call actors. Pros - autoscaling out of box, as for each message from queue new actor will be created. Cons - actors will be disposable.

Comment: Does data need to persist between task runs? If so, actors become much less feasible.

Comment: No, basically worker get request message process it in some way and returns execution

Comment: As for option 1: you can create multiple instances of a service to scale out. So you could have multiple service instances processing the same queue

Comment: The problem with option 1 is no way to create new instances and remove them on fly depending on load

Comment: Aren't stateless services generally 1-1 with a cluster node? If this is true in your scenario can you create a nodetype specifically for the service and configure the scale-set to auto re-balance based on desired metrics (cpu usage, mem usage etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider creating 2 types of stateless services:

1. Service that monitors the task queue depth. This service will create and remove instances of Service 2 based on the amount of queued tasks.
2. Service that processes queued jobs.